# How to use Facebook Access Token for App Development purposes

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing my own app and am using Facebook login as user generation to avoid having to create my own login system. I am having trouble thinking of a completely safe way to make it such that a user can send me their user token or something from Facebook to be interpreted and transformed into a UUID. What is the best way to do this? Is it not my problem if another app developer uses tokens sent to them for malicious things in my app?

Comment: Did you google this? Facebook provided guidance: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Comment: Ah I missed this, thanks!

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam no, "purposes" is correct here